# Transformation from one position scale of notation to another

Tags: c#, algorithm

How can I transform from one scale of notation to another using my custom function by C#.

```
abstract string Convert(string value, string fromBase, string toBase);
```

**value** - string representation scale of notation in basic  notation

**fromBase** - string represent the base of numeric

**toBase** - string representation the base of numeric which you must to transform

**P.S.**
string which represents the base position scale of notation can include any symbols for represent numeral ascending order

**For example**

Value = “GSAK”

```
   fromBase = “A,S,G,K” – four(4) is the base scale of notation (If write arabic figures:  0,1,2,3)
   toBase= “0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9” – ten(10) is the base scale of notation
   return value = “147”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first translate the input value to one of the numeric data types (i.e. long), and then encode into the target format. Draft implementation of a class to do the parsing and encoding (untested and certainly not optimal):

```
public class Formatter
{
  List<char> symbols;
  int base;

  public Formatter(string format)
  {
    string[] splitted = format.Split(",");
    symbols = splitted.Select(x => x[0]).ToList();
    base = symbols.Size;
  }

  public long Parse(string value)
  {
    long result = 0;
    foreach(char c in value)
    {
      long n = symbols.IndexOf(c);
      result = result*base+n;
    }
    return result;
  }

  public string Encode(long value)
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(value>0)
    {
      long n = value % base;
      value /= base;
      sb.Insert(0, symbols[n]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your class converts  to 10 scale of notation ONLY. I need convert to some  scale of notation.

Comment: Hi @Grienders, you need to create an instance of this class for every scale. The scale should be determined by the length of the list of symbols provided. Why are you saying that its 10 scale only?

Comment: Your class converts TO decimal notation ONLY, isn't it??

Comment: How does your class determine the base numeric of scale I need to convert? not the base numeric of scale FROM  I need to convert!  the desctionation base numeric of scale  I need to convert! How?